# Possible on UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, union

I have a master table with USER and COMPANY called USER1, which maps a user to a company that the user can access and I have another master table that has a list of all available companies called COMPANY1.  If a User is assigned '' company in USER1 table then it means that the user can access all companies in the COMPANY1 table.

```
USER1 table

User          |          Company
username1     |          MyCompany2
username2     |          MyCompany1
username3     |          
username4     |        



COMPANY1 table

Index       |      Company
1           |      MyCompany1
2           |      MyCompany2
3           |      MyCompany3
4           |      MyCompany4
```

Is there any way for me to do a UNION ALL to get the following:

```
NEW table

User          |          Company
username1     |          MyCompany2
username2     |          MyCompany1
username3     |          MyCompany1
username3     |          MyCompany2
username3     |          MyCompany3
username3     |          MyCompany4
username4     |          MyCompany1
username4     |          MyCompany2
username4     |          MyCompany3
username4     |          MyCompany4
```

I would really appreciate any input on this matter. :)

I tried something like

```
SELECT [User], [Company Name] FROM [USER1]
WHERE [Company Name] <> ''

UNION ALL

SELECT [User],
(SELECT [Company] FROM [COMPANY1]) [Company Name]
FROM [USER1]
WHERE [Company Name] = ''
```

Obviously this gave me an error that I can only have one result. :(  How do I loop through one table like the COMPANY1 table based on the result of another table like USER1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` of the `Company1` table to the users with the user's assigned company of `''` and this will produce one row for each user and each company pair, and will allow for your `UNION ALL`, like so:

```
SELECT [User], [Company Name] 
FROM [USER1] 
WHERE [Company Name] <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT u.[User], c.[Company] as [Company Name]
FROM [USER1] as u
CROSS JOIN [Company1] as c
WHERE u.[Company Name] = ''
```

Documentation with examples for `CROSS JOIN` : [sql-cross-join-with-examples](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-cross-join-with-examples/)

Comment: OMG!!  I have never heard of CROSS APPLY before.  It works completely as expected and I don't even need to try and figure out some loops. 10 out 5 for the quick reply and the spot on answer!

Comment: @clinton Glad to help. Be careful with using this though, if your table of users with a company equal to `''` and your company table continues to grow, it could cause long query results as it has to create those pairs over and over again. Depending on how you are using this query, if it's say to display information to a user via a web page or some other GUI, it may be better to just pull down each Company Name and get the users which have a company equal to `''` in a separate result set and then add these to the results.

Comment: @clinton You could also try placing some indexes on your tables as well if you are going to stick with the `CROSS JOIN` and it may help improve performance.

Comment: The reply that I marked as an answer mentioned CROSS APPLY but I also tried the recent one which mentioned CROSS JOIN and both showed the same result so another 10 out of 5 for you. :)  I only have a small table so running both queries did not show any discernible difference so let me use it in my everyday queries and see what happens. Thanks again.